# Nginx to point to different subdomains

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, subdomain

I have a domain (example.com) that I am trying to use subdomains to show different parts of the applications. Right now is all Hosted in AWS.

This is sort of the set up I am trying to go for.

sbx.example.com
trn.example.com
office.example.com

My nginx conf right now is as follow:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html/apt-front/dist;
    
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
    
             location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
             }
    
        location /api{
          alias "/var/www/html/api/public";
          try_files $uri $uri/ @api;
              location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/mint-api/public/index.php;
        }
         }
    
           location @api {
                rewrite /api/(.*)$ /api/index.php?/$1 last;
           }
    
    
        include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;

}
```

I know that in AWS i would need to create a record for the domain, i believe that would be a NS record with the name of the subdomain (such as sbx.example.com).   What I was thinking of doing is creating another repository (a clone) with the changes that i need for SBX, create another server block and under server name just change the subdomain?  Thoughts?

Comment: What's the question? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not difficult, but there's a few steps

- Create your Route53 hosted zone
- Register your domain, enter the R53 name servers
- Create A record for the main domain
- Create CNAME records for each subdomain, pointing at the main domain
- Nginx is configured to respond to each of the domains. That they are subdomains is irrelevant to Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that in AWS i would need to create a record for the domain

Yes, in any DNS you'd have to.

> i believe that would be a NS record with the name of the subdomain

This would be a "A" record. This will point your Name (Domain) to your host (IP). "NS" ist for "Nameservers".

> (such as sbx.example.com)

Exactly. Like this:

```
sbx.example.com. 1800  IN  A    127.0.0.172
```

Then just redirect the subdomain's request to the folders (or URIs) you need.